# Calculate $15^{843} \pmod{11}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Calculate $15^{843} \pmod{11}$

My solution

Fermat's little theorem

Since $15 \equiv 4 \pmod{11}$ and according Fermat's Little Theorem

$$4^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}\;,$$ we shall have

$$15^{843} \equiv 4^{843} \equiv 4^{840} \times 4^3 \equiv (4^{10})^{84} \times 4^3 \equiv 4^3 \equiv 64 \equiv 9 \pmod{11}$$

Is this correct$?$

Comment: Yup you are right...

Comment: yes, it is correct!

Comment: Aboslutely correct. Alternatively, if you are good at numbers, then $15^5 = 1$ (mod 11), and then the result is $15^3$ (mod 11) which is $9$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

It is.

[Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is indeed one very useful tool to finding the answer, and in case you have any doubt whether you got that part right, you can verify that:

$$4^{10}=1048576=11\times 95325+1\equiv1\pmod{11}$$

The rest is just using the properties of modular arithmetic to replace some terms by congruent but simpler terms. Done explicitely, and correctly, so I see no reason to doubt the result.